# Radeon Card not showing up on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I have a Radeon HD 8770 M on my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 (fresh install).

I wanted to follow the instruction [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) to load the proprietary fglrx driver.

When I run the first command

```
lspci -vvnn | grep VGA
```

my output is

```
VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
```

[..omitted the rest]

and the Radeon doesn't show up.

If I run just

```
 lspci
```

I can find it

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
```

The switch file

```
ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

is present so I tried to turn it on with the switch command

```
echo ON > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

but to no avail.

How can I make it work?